# ImageMap behavior for tiles

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible to determine the area on which a user clicked on a tile? Just like an image map in HTML. I would like to specify two buttons at an image tile and carry out different actions for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to do this.

With respect of lauching your app, the tile works just like a shortcut on your PC desktop.

If you really need the behaviour you describe you'll have to create 2 applications - 1 for each launch action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for every UI element.

```
private void ListBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      string pos=  e.GetPosition(CanvasForLoop).X.ToString();
    }
```